# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc90u.lib'

Tags: c++, static-libraries

`error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc90u.lib'`

I have converted VC++ project from VS2008 to VS2012. After the conversion i am getting the linker error, error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc90u.lib' . I am not explicitly referring mfc90u.lib in my vcproj file. I added vc110u.lib under Configuration Properties-> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies. but still the issue is not resolved. Any help to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Go to your project settings `Configuration Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset` and make sure you're building for Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Hello PaulMcKenzie, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Did it solve the issue?  If it did, I will move it to an answer.

Comment: Hello PaulMcKenzie,                                                                            Thanks for the reply. I am using Visual Studio 2012 for building the project. I do not have any other compilers installed. The issue is not solved.

Comment: The platform Tool set is set to Visual Studio 2012 (v110)

Comment: Are you linking in other libraries built with VC 9?  If so, then that is where the app is getting `mfc90u.lib` from.

Comment: I am trying to link AutoCAD 2012 libraries from my project. I think its built with VS2008.

Comment: Well, that may explain why you have an issue.  You're using libraries that depend on earlier versions of MFC.  You could turn on the `/verbose` flag in the linker settings to determine which of these libraries are reliant on mfc90u.lib